# Possible number of ways there can be trips in poker

Tags: combinatorics

How many different ways can you be dealt five cards, and have exactly three cards of the same value?

Assume standard playing cards (52 distinct cards, 4 suits, 13 values)

Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you choose the rank for which it has trips. There are $13$ ranks to choose from.

Next, you choose the 3 (out of 4 symbols) to be chosen for trips. That's ${4 \choose 3}$.

Then, you choose the kicker, which cannot be paired; so we decide to choose the ranks first. There are 12 left ranks, so $12\choose 2$ ranks to chose the kickers' ranks.

Finally, we chose the symbol for each of the kicker. It's simply ${4 \choose 1}$ symbols for each kicker, so in total ${4 \choose 1}^2$ ways of choosing symbol for both kickers.

In total, it should be $13\times {4\choose 3} \times {12\choose 2} \times {4\choose 1}^2=54,912$ ways.

Comment: Since the kicker cannot be paired, don't you have to do 12*11 instead of 12 choose 2? Can you elaborate on this step please?

Comment: No; by doing $12\times 11$, you are invoking an order on the ranks chosen. The following choice will be counted as distinct choices: 4 first and 3 second, versus 3 first and 4 second. This will double count the possibility of kickers: say 4s3s vs 3s4s will be counted as distinct kickers.